# Google maps v3: syntax to change mapType on click event

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a v3 Google map initialised as a ROADMAP that I want to change to a HYBRID map on a particular click event being handled by a jQuery function:

```
$('#cft').click(function() {
  map.setCenter($cft);
  map.setZoom(18);
  map.setMapType(HYBRID);
  return false;
});
```

On click the map recenters and zooms as required but the mapType remains a ROADMAP so clearly this syntax doesn't work!

Is there a method like the above that does, or do I have to initialise a new map?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Obvious now I see it! (Can't vote the answer up because I don't have enough rep yet.)